# opencv contour get the dark region only

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, contour, image-thresholding

New to Opencv.
I converted to grayscale and inverted an image. After applying thresholding to it this is the result.
[image]

I need to get only the dark (yellow) regions from this image but instead plotting gives me this.
[image]

This is the code that I'm using currently to get the 'contours' image. I want to plot just the buildings i.e. the yellow boxes only.

The contour code works perfectly with the non-inverted image to plot roads.

```
img = cv.cvtColor(sample_img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
imagem = cv.bitwise_not(img)#inverted image
ret, thresh = cv.threshold(imagem, 6, 6, cv.THRESH_BINARY)
contours = cv.findContours(thresh, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[-2]

blank = np.zeros((500,640,3), dtype = np.uint8)
contour_img = cv.drawContours(blank, contours, -1, (255,255,255), 3)
plt.imshow(contour_img)
```

Comment: instead of threshold use the inRange function from opencv and specify the yellow color in that range

Comment: Don't use pyplot to view your data as it applies a false color. Use cv2.imshow() and/or cv2.imwrite().  Be sure your regions are white not black if you want to find Contours.

Comment: Thank you @Micka . Using inRange helped with the gray images.